# Knockout.js doesn't pick up autocompleted or prefilled values

Tags: knockout.js, remember-me

I've noticed that Knockout doesn't seem to update my view model when I use autocomplete (remembering password, for example).

I read that there was an issue with this, but should have been fixed by now. It doesn't seem to be working for me though.

I've hosted a mini-example of the problem, if you fill in random string + password, press save and "remember password" and use the autocomplete feature the observables email and password doesn't get updated until you focus the relevant textbox and then leave focus.

This is tested using IE 9 or Firefox 18.

The reason I don't use fiddle is because I didn't seem to be able to trigger the autocomplete feature.

Any ideas?

http://cyberrascal.no-ip.org/tempsite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is overwritten by the value binding, please have a look at this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/TeFAX/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueWithInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var value = element.value;

        observable(value);   

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    },
    update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
};
```

Also you must wait until the value is set by the browser

```
setTimeout(function() { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); }, 15);
```

Comment: This works for pre-filled values, but not autocompleted ones using "remember password" :( Any fix?

Comment: Very strange, the remember password feature worked for me the first time around, but after I udated password and username it stopped working...

Comment: I struggled with the same issue for a while and my 'solution' was to just disable autocomplete on the username & password fields. Not ideal but at least the bindings are working correctly.